# Detecting when TinyMCE is "ready"

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to add some custom JS functionality to the default "post" editing screen that depends upon TinyMCE being instantiated and ready to rock.  If I try to make the changes before TinyMCE is set up, I (obviously) receive JS errors.

Without needing to modify any core files, and ideally using JS/jQuery events alone (i.e. not PHP/WP hooks/filters or polling with JS' `setInterval()`), **is there a way to detect when TinyMCE is ready?**

Comment: FYI, we're still on a version of WP that uses TinyMCE 3 (as opposed to the newer TinyMCE 4).

Answer (score 9):

Unless your WP version is truly ancient, you should be able to use the `tinymce-editor-init` event triggered on editor `init` by "wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wordpress/plugin.js", eg (assuming your script is loading after jQuery):

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'tinymce-editor-init', function( event, editor ) {
    // Blah.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but it should work:

```
is_tinyMCE_active = false;
if ( typeof( tinyMCE) != "undefined" ) {
    if ( tinyMCE.activeEditor == null || tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden() != false ) {
        is_tinyMCE_active = true;
    }
}
```